# Can't arrange data into a table format

Tags: php, arrays, variables

I cannot get this to sit correctly into a table structure, as far as I can see all of the coding is correct but it just isn't working for some reason.

Here is my code:

```
<?php
    echo "<table class='array'>
        <tr><th>&nbsp;&nbsp; Employee &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>In Que &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Incomplete &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</th>
        <th>Processed </th></tr>";
    $count_result=array();
    $path = "Users";
    $folders = @scandir("$path");
    if ($folders) {
        foreach ($folders as $item) {
            $count = 0;
            if ((substr($item, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $item)))
                continue;
            if (is_dir($path . "/" . $item)) {
                $target_folders = @scandir($path . "/" . $item . "/uploaded/");   
                if ($target_folders) {
                    foreach ($target_folders as $target_item) { 
                        if ((substr($target_item, 0, 1) == '.') || is_dir("$path/$item/uploaded/$target_item"))
                            continue;
                        $count++;
                    }
                }
                $count_result[$item]=$count;
            }
             echo "<tr><td><div class='data'>" .$item."
                </div></td>";
             echo "<td><div class='data1'>" .$count."
                </div></td>";
        }
    }
?>

<?php
    $counta_result=array();
    $path = "Users";
    $foldersa = @scandir("$path");
    if ($foldersa) {
        foreach ($foldersa as $itema) {
            $counta = 0;
            if ((substr($itema, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $itema)))
                continue;
            if (is_dir($path . "/" . $itema)) {
                $target_foldersa = @scandir($path . "/" . $itema . "/incomplete/");
                if ($target_foldersa) {
                    foreach ($target_foldersa as $target_itema) {
                        if ((substr($target_itema, 0, 1) == '.') || is_dir("$path/$itema/uploaded/$target_itema"))
                            continue;
                        $counta++;
                    }
                }
                $counta_result[$itema]=$counta;
            }
            echo "<td><div class='data2'>" .$counta."</div></td>";
        }
    } 
?>

<?php
    $countb_result=array();
    $path = "Users";
    $foldersb = @scandir("$path");
    if ($foldersb) {
        foreach ($foldersb as $itemb) {
            $countb = 0;
            if ((substr($itemb, 0, 1) == '.') || (preg_match("/\.php$/", $itemb)))
                continue;
            if (is_dir($path . "/" . $itemb)) {
                $target_foldersb = @scandir($path . "/" . $itemb . "/processed/");
                if ($target_foldersb) {
                    foreach ($target_foldersb as $target_itemb) {
                        if ((substr($target_itemb, 0, 1) == '.') || is_dir("$path/$itemb/processed/$target_itemb"))
                            continue;
                        $countb++;
                    }
                }
                $countb_result[$itemb]=$countb;
            }
            echo "<td><div class='data3'>" .$countb."</div></td></tr>";
        }
    } 
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Don't do what you just did with `blah blah` else it won't take a minute for others to downvote your question and close it

Comment: only reason i did was because it was requiring the text for me to submit it

Comment: Because *coding is correct but it just isn't working for some reason* is too vague, you need to properly format your code, explain in detail, so that users get a clear view of what you are asking for

Comment: and as you can see the issue is a pretty straight forward one

Comment: http://ccrxpersonnel.com/maindisplay.php

Comment: that is what i am talking about

Comment: Press `ctrl+u` and you will get your answer

Comment: the first 2 colloms are correct but after that the numbers just do their own thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are iterating the same set of items three times. The first loop creates a `<tr>` at the beginning of each iteration, and the last creates a `</tr>` at the end of each. So, the first loop is working "correctly", filling in the first two columns, and then moving to the next row. The second then just places all of its data on the last row, and the third adds data and a new row. Rather than looping over the same data three times, you should just have one loop that populates the columns as needed. At the very beginning of each iteration, add a `<tr>`, and at the end, add a `</tr>`

See this [fiddle](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/wfn-hyu). This doesn't have access to whatever directories you need, so I replaced the `scandir` calls with `array_fill`s, but you can see the formatting is as it should be. Note: there are plenty of additional optimizations to make to the code; this is just to show that combining the three loops into one will help with this specific issue.

Answer (score 1):

1) The answer to your actual question is that you are missing a `</tr>` in your initial for loop, and missing an opening `<tr>` in your second for loop. So, either you are actually missing these things, or something is wrong with your bracketing.

2) You probably missed this because your code is poorly formatted. If you avoid "echoing" blocks of HTML where you dont have to, IDE's syntax highlighting may be able to spot this mistake (depending on your IDE), it also makes your code quite a bit cleaner.

Comment: +1 Right idea, although the problem is even more involved than that